# How to split large dataframe by columns and write into individual CSVs

Tags: r

I have a large csv file `new.dat` with 100s of column names. I want to split `new.dat` per column names keeping first column in all new subset written as `.csv`.

`new.dat`

```
new.dat <- structure(list(Sequence = c("AAAAAACCTGTTCTGATA", "AAAAAAGGCTGTTACTGAGC", 
"AAAAACATTCGAGCGAGATCTCT", "AAAAACCTCGACTTCGGAAG", "AAAAAGCTCGTAGTTGAA", 
"AAAAAGCTCGTAGTTGAAC"), WT1 = c("84", "104", "80", "35", "112", 
"350"), WT2 = c("149", "478", "502", "186", "577", "911"), AGO1 = c("32", 
"147", "433", "51", "258", "353"), AGO2 = c("37", "222", "355", 
"85", "408", "420"), DCL1 = c("56", "185", "291", "48", "167", 
"273"), DCL2 = c("59", "176", "294", "31", "185", "245"), NAs = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Sequence", "WT1", "WT2", "AGO1", 
"AGO2", "DCL1", "DCL2", "NAs"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

So the result from `new.dat` data should have seven csv files. The first csv `WT1.csv` with `Sequence` and `WT1` columns, second csv file `WT2.csv` with `Sequence` and `WT2` columns and so forth..

This is the code I have tried. Please suggest what I am missing here.
Thanks

```
for (name in colnames(new.dat[-1])){
   tmp=subset(new.dat$Sequence, colnames==name)
   fn= name
   #Save the CSV file 
   write.csv(tmp,fn,row.names=FALSE)
 }
```

Comment: Did you meant that you have multiple `WT1` columns?  If so, do you have any patterns.  Are these the prefixes?

Comment: @akrun No, I want to keep `Sequence` column and one additional column in  all new csv files. The column names are unique and non-repetitive.

Comment: If that is the case, loop through the columns and cbind with the first column i.e. `lst <- Map(function(x,y, z) setNames(cbind(x, y), c("Sequence", z)), list(new.dat[1]), new.dat[-1], names(new.dat)[-1])` and write it to csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just loop over the column names except the first one with `lapply`, subset the columns of the dataset by including the 'Sequence' column and write it to file

```
lapply(names(new.dat)[-1], function(nm) 
   write.csv(new.dat[c("Sequence", nm)], 
       paste0(nm, ".csv"), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easier using column indexes.

```
for (i in 2:ncol(new.dat)) {
    tmp=new.dat[,c(1,i)]
    name=colnames(new.dat)[i]
    fn = paste0(name,".csv")
   print(fn)
   #Save the CSV file 
   write.csv(tmp,fn,row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add a part to change the name of the file. It should be working now.